# how to save array with useEffect React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I want save array data using react useEffect. Follow Example with class:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const users = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');

  if (users) {
   this.setState({ users: JSON.parse(users) });
  }
 }

 componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
  const { users } = this.state;

  if (prevState.users !== users) {
   AsyncStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
  }
 }
```

how to implement the logic with React Hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `componentDidMount` logic you can use `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFetch = async () => {
    const users = await AsyncStorage.getItem("users");
    if (users) {
      // setter from useState
      setUsers(JSON.parse(users));
    }
  };
  asyncFetch();
}, []);
```

For `componentDidMount` use `useEffect` with dep array and `useRef` reference.

```
const prevUsers = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  const prevUsers = prevUsers.current;

  // Some equal check function
  if (!areEqual(prevUsers, users)) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
  }

  prevUsers.current = users;
}, [users]);
```

> Notice that in your current code, `prevState.users !== users` is always truley, you comparing two objects and in JS `{} !== {}` always results `true`.

Comment: it worked very well, I just had to adjust some details. Thank you Dennis Vash

Comment: Follow my adjust: 

useEffect(() => {
    //AsyncStorage.clear();
    const asyncFetch = async () => {
      const numbers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('list');
      if (numbers) {
        // setter from useState
        setList(JSON.parse(numbers));
      }
    };
    asyncFetch();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const prevListi = prevList.current;
    // Some equal check function
    if (prevListi !== list) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
    }
    // prevListi.current = list;
  }, [list]);

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below and you can use hooks in functional based component not class based component

```
//state declaration similar to class based component
const [usersdata,setUsers] = useState([]); 

const users = await JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem('users')); 

//whenever the value of users changes useEffect will reset the value of users in state useEffect handle the lifecycle in function based component
useEffect(()=>{
      if(users){
         setUsers(JSON.parse(users));
      }
},[users])
```

Answer (score 0):

For hooks the logic changes slightly, you would have to "hook" your effect with a state in order to update the component, so the component would update (`componentDidUpdate`) when the hooked state has been updated, you can obviously hook multiple states.

If you choose to not hook any state, the effect would execute only at the mounting of the component just like (`componentDidMount()`)

I don't see the logic that makes you decide when to update the user state since you always get it from the storage, so I will assume that you have some kind of a trigger that makes you verify if the users value has changed in the storage.

so you can refactor your code like this:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [userHasChanged, setUserHasChanged] = useState(false);

usEffect(async () => {
  // comparing the old users with the new users is not useful since you always fetch the users from the storage, so the optimal is to always set the new array/ object to users, this way you avoid comparing the two objects which is a bit costly.

 const newUsers = await AsyncStorage.getItem("users");
 setUsers(JSON.parse(newUsers));

 setUserHasChanged(false);
  
}, [userHasChanged])

// some code that triggers userHasChanged, you use setUserHasChaned(true)
```